# Proper way to make hundreds database update?

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions, sql-update

I have a function that each minute queries Google BigQuery, and I want to use BigQuery results to update rows in another relational database.

I was trying to do something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = BigQueryResult_Row1_MyField WHERE a_id = BigQueryResult_Row1_a_id
    UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = BigQueryResult_Row2_MyField WHERE a_id = BigQueryResult_Row2_a_id
    UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = BigQueryResult_Row3_MyField WHERE a_id = BigQueryResult_Row3_a_id
    .
    .
    .
    UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = BigQueryResult_RowN_MyField WHERE a_id = BigQueryResult_RowN_a_id
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

That is an `UPDATE` statement for each bigquery row. I can't do a single `UPDATE` statement combined with `SELECT` statement because data come from BigQuery, not from another database table.

Trying to execute this transaction, I get timeout error, so I want to ask: is this a proper way to do hundred updates at a time? There could even be thousand updates at a time in some cases. How can I do that in a better way?

Comment: Why not insert the data into a staging table, update with `select`, then drop your staging table?

Comment: What sort of timeout error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renat's answer is fine.  But a more colloquial way of writing uses `values()`:

```
UPDATE t 
        SET MyField = v.MyField       
    FROM MyTable t JOIN
         (VALUES ('BigQueryResult_Row1_MyField', 'BigQueryResult_Row1_a_id'),
                 ('BigQueryResult_Row2_MyField', 'BigQueryResult_Row2_a_id'),
                 ('BigQueryResult_Row3_MyField', 'BigQueryResult_Row3_a_id'),
                 ('BigQueryResult_RowN_MyField', 'BigQueryResult_RowN_a_id')
         ) v(MyField, a_id)
        ON v.a_id = t.a_id;
```

In general, using `UNION` when you intend `UNION ALL` is a bad idea -- because `UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  In this case, a table constructor is a simpler solution anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about UNION ovehead. Anyway, is there any limitation in defining temp table with VALUES or I can add thousand values?

Comment: @AlessioInnocenzi . . . No.  Eventually you will hit limits on query length.  These can be imposed by intermediate layers.  If you have more than a few hundred rows, you might think about storing them in a table and bulk inserting them.  Or, if the data starts out in a table in the database, then just use a subquery instead of explicit values.

Answer (score 0):

Does a query like this work without timeout (using temp table as suggested @JohnHC)?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

;WITH UpdateTempTable AS (
    SELECT 'BigQueryResult_Row1_MyField' As MyField, 'BigQueryResult_Row1_a_id' AS a_id
    UNION SELECT 'BigQueryResult_Row2_MyField', 'BigQueryResult_Row2_a_id'
    UNION SELECT 'BigQueryResult_Row3_MyField', 'BigQueryResult_Row3_a_id'
    UNION SELECT 'BigQueryResult_RowN_MyField', 'BigQueryResult_RowN_a_id'
  ) UPDATE MyTable 
        SET MyTable.MyField = UpdateTempTable.MyField       
    FROM MyTable 
        JOIN UpdateTempTable ON UpdateTempTable.a_id = MyTable.a_id;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you very much for the answer and thank to @JohnHC for the suggestion

Comment: This is a great answer, but @Gordon Linoff anwer is more appropriate in this case, since I have to add hundred or thousand values and overhead is an important variable. For this reason I'm gonna change the accepted answer.